# Issue to filter on table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I have a JSON data like this:

```
[
  {
  "id": 6488,
  "type": "table",
  "content": "<table> <tbody> <tr> <td>First</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Second</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Third</td> </tr></tbody> </table>"
  }, {
    "id": 123123,
    "type": "another",
    "content": "xxxx"
  }
]
```

I'm using [**ngBindHtml**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) to display the `content`, and it's working really well. The problem is only one: When the type is equivalent to `table` I want to make a filter on this, is there a way to do this? I searched a lot and I couldn't find a solution for this.

The **view** looks like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Filter..." ng-model="$ctrl.search">
<p></p>
<strong>Id</strong>
<p ng-bind="$ctrl.item.id"></p>
<strong>Type</strong>
<p ng-bind="$ctrl.item.type"></p>
<strong>Content</strong>
<p ng-bind-html="$ctrl.item.content"></p>
```

Here's a link for [**demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Kt6gM2aV7CCRXkmVBCyH?p=preview) so you could understand the situation better.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where do you cant to apply your filter ?

Comment: I want to use the `filter` in table.. like in the common way that we can use it, ex: `<tr ng-repeat="bla in blabla | filter: $ctrl.search track by $index></tr>`. However it's coming from webservice.. and I can't figure what on how to transform this.. did you get it?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal of your filter is too search then here is what you can do:

```
 <div class="form-group">
 <input class="form-control" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search_points">
 </div>
```

and add ->  `ng-repeat="p in Product.productPoints | filter:search_points"`
and bind it like {{p.code}} instead of ng bind

for Reference visit -> [This](https://scotch.io/tutorials/sort-and-filter-a-table-using-angular)

Comment: Well, I think you didn't understand what is the question.. I know how to filter a table like this.. the problem is that the table is coming with all items from webservice.